# Using-like statement for template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, using-directives

Suppose there is the following definition in a header

```
namespace someNamespace {
    template<class T, class S>
    int operator + (const T & t, const S & s) {
        return specialAdd (t, s);
    }
}
```

Now I would like the user of the header to be able to do something like

```
using someNamespace::operator + <OneClass,SecondClass>;
```

which is obviously not possible.

The reason for this is that I do not want my operator + interfere with the standard operator + and therefore give the user the possibility to specify for which types operator + should be defined. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the barton-nackman trick: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick

```
template<typename T,typename S>
class AddEnabled{
    friend int operator + (T const& t, const S & s) {
      T temp(t);
      return temp.add(s);
    }
};

class MyClass: public AddEnabled<MyClass,int>{
  public:

    MyClass(int val):mVal(val){

    }

    int add(int s){
      mVal+=s;
      return mVal;
    }

  private:
    int mVal;
};
```

Here another example to overload the << operator:

```
template<typename T>
class OutEnabled {
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T const& val) {
      return static_cast<OutEnabled<T> const&>(val).ioprint(out);
    }    

  protected:
    template<typename U>
    U& ioprint(U& out) const {
      return static_cast<T const*>(this)->print(out);
    }
};
```

To use it you can either let your class inherit from OutEnabled:

```
class MyClass: public OutEnabled<MyClass>{ ...
```

or you can define a sentry object e.g. in an anonymous namespace in a cpp file

```
namespace{
 OutEnabled<MyClass> sentry;
}
```

As soon as the template OutEnabled gets instantiated (`OutEnabled<MyClass>`) the GLOBAL operator `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, MyClass const& val)` 
exists.

Further MyClass must contain a function (template) matching

```
 template<typename U>
 U& print(U& out) const {
   out << mBottomLeft << "\t"<< mW << "\t"<< mH;
   return out;
 }
```

Since this is called by `ioprint`.

The function `U& ioprint(U& out)` is not absolutely necessary but it gives you a better error message if you do not have defined `print` in `MyClass`.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's a really nice solution. Am I right in assuming that there is no possibility to achieve this on a "block" level, i.e. to make the operator be defined in some block of code but not in another? (I.e. `operator + (C, D)` exists somewhere in the code but somewhere it does not?)

Comment: @JohnB: Depends how you put it. If you put the anonymous namespace in a cpp the operator will be valid for this cpp but IMHO for nothing else. Alas I'm not completely sure about that and the easiest way would be to try it. Why do you need it for only one block by the way?

Answer (score 1):

A type traits class that they can specialize, and enable_if in the operator+?  Put the operator+ in the global namespace, but it returns

```
std::enable_if< for::bar<c1>::value && for::bar<c2>::value, int >
```

Where bar is a template type traits class in namespace for like this:

```
template<class T>
struct bar: std::false_type {};
```

I think that should cause sfinae to make your template plus only match stuff you specialize bar to accept.

You might want to throw some deconst and ref stripping into that enable_if, and do some perfect forwarding in your operator+ as well.